# jQuery UI state hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-hover

I am facing an issue with jQuery UI 1.8.5 UI-state-hover style, I have an XHTML page with date picker and input mask defined on this page, like this:

`<p:calenda value='#dateBean.fromDate'>

<p:inputMask value='dateBean.fromTime'>`

Also, I have several buttons on this page and I defined the UI-state-hover like this:

```
border: 1px solid #99ccff;
background: #3a71c9 url(images/s.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ffffff;
```

Question here is,

If I hover the mouse on date picker or input mask, the size of input field of date picker and time input mask will be changed. And if I change the border style from 'solid' to 'hidden', the date picker and time input mask work well, but buttons size will be smaller.

Anyone who can help me on this, many thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not really a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outline: 1px solid #99ccff;
background: #3a71c9 url(images/s.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ffffff;
```

border adds the 1px to your full width and height (+2px). outline doesn't.